# How to print SQL query in spark-sql CLI?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql to execute big SQL files. I want to log SQL query before spark executes it, something similar to hive verbose mode. I have tried spark-sql CLI with `-v` parameter to verbose but still, it doesn't print SQL query.

```
spark-sql -v \
<configuration parameters> \
-f abc.sql
```

**Hive command:**

```
hive -v \
<configuration parameters> \
-f abc.sql
```

Is there any other spark configuration that I am missing to print SQL query?

Comment: you can store your query as a string. Then in case u are using any logger then log that string there.Something like:- String sqlQuery= /*mysqlQuery*/; sparl.sql(sqlQuery). Logger.print(sqlQuery)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am using spark-sql CLI which allows to run only SQL queries, there are no ways to access any objects like sparkContext, logger or sparkSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark-sql verbose mode is `--v` whereas hive verbose mode is `-v`. 

Below command works for me-

```
spark-sql --v \
<configuration parameters> \
-f abc.sql
```